# Examples of textbook definition: Chaper 5, Warner.

Tags: general-topology

This is a question about a specific definition and its examples.

The following definition is taken from Warner's Differentiable Manifolds and Lie groups, chapter $5$:

> Definition: Let $S$ and $X$ be topological spaces. A continuous map $\phi:S\rightarrow X$ is a sheaf of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules if the following three conditions are satisfied:
>
> 1. $\phi$ is a local homomorphism
> 2. For all points $x\in X$, $\phi^{-1}(x)$ is endowed with an abelian group structure
> 3. The operation $(s_2,s_1)\rightarrow s_2-s_1$ is continuous $S\circ S\rightarrow S$ where $S\circ S$ is the subspace of $S\times S$ consisting of the pairs $(s_2,s_1)$ above the same point on $X$ ($\phi(s_1)=\phi(s_2)$).

By this definition, one can show that (hope I didn't make any mistake):

1. The covering $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^1$ (endowed with a $\mathbb{Z}$ on each fiber) is not a sheaf. One can show that the operation $(s_2,s_1)\rightarrow s_2-s_1$ is not continuous. Another way to see that this is not a sheaf is by taking the $0$ section over $\mathbb{S}^1$: it is not a continuous section.
2. The skyscraper sheaf $O_0(\mathbb{Z})$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is homemorphic to the bug-eyed line.

Are there other examples (counterexamples) of sheaves with known-elsewhere topologies?

---

So I think maybe the covering $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^1$ is not a sheaf with the usual topology. It can be made into a sheaf if $\mathbb{R}$ is endowed with a finer topology (e.g. the discrete topology, then the operation would become automatically continuous; or the Zariski topology).

Temporary conclusion: when we talk about sheaf, the topology is often strictly finer than the euclidean one.

Comment: I think the first condition should be local homeomorphism.

Comment: How do you show for your first example that the operation is not continous ?

Comment: Yes it is a local homeo. I just write down the operation in $\mathbb{R}^2$. In that case $S\circ S$ is a union of parallel lines, and the operation from this union to the vertical axis is visually discontinuous.

Comment: So $S\circ S$ is the subset $\coprod_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} \{y = x + k\}\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with the subset topology. Then $x-y = k$, for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, take an open in $U$ in $\mathbb{R}$, then the pre-image of $U$ by the function is given by $\coprod_{k \in U\cap \mathbb{Z}} \{y = x + k\}$ which is open in $S \circ S$. So I think it is continous.

Comment: By the way, "topologies of sheaves" is much more reminiscent of a concept in topos theory than it is reminiscent of this definition, so you might want to consider changing the title.  (Personally, I would be more likely to call this something like an abelian group bundle - and "examples of sheaves" could also be misleading to some people who would be expecting the question to be about the definition of sheaf from algebraic geometry.)

Comment: The problem beeing than bundle should be more kind of locally constant sheafs, (or local triviality) here If you want the skyscraper example you really need to talk about sheafs.

Comment: The sheaf is produced by taking $U$ maps to sections of the local homeomorphism defined on $U$, the other way around is by taking the étale space, and this should be inverse equivalences of categories.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I'll edit the title.

Comment: @jeanmfischer take for example the preimage of the open interval $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2})$, its preimage is a union of disjoint intervals in $S\circ S$, with two types: $[)$ and $()$, and is not open.

Comment: @jeanmfischer by the way if one follows the $0$ section on the covering $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^1$, there'll be a point where it becomes discontinuous (a jump to the previous level). Hence the $0$ section is not a continuous section (whereas if it was a sheaf, the $0$ section is a continuous section).

Comment: @jeanmfischer ah maybe the problem lies in the choice of topology over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Now I have lost all my certitudes, but that there is not a global section should not be a problem. And I still se the preimage of your interval as the entire line $y=x + 1$. Will check thoroughly today :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any abelian group, for example $\mathbb{Z}$, then for any topological space $X$, the projection map $\mathbb{Z}\times X \to X$ is a sheaf of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules in the sense of your definition, having put the trivial topology on $\mathbb{Z}$ and the product topology on $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{R}$.

For the $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{S}^1$ example :

The map $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $(x,y)\mapsto y-x$ is a continous mapping, and $\mathbb{R} \times_{ \mathbb{S}^1} \mathbb{R}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, it should still be continous on that subspace.

On $\mathbb{S}^1$, we have the maps $\mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^1$, $z \mapsto z^n$ (if you see $\mathbb{S}^1 = \{z\in \mathbb{C}, |z| = 1\}$), the preimage of $0$ is $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Here you get the same discussion that the universal cover for the circle, $\mathbb{S}^1\times_{\mathbb{S}^1} \mathbb{S}^1$ is a subspace of the torous (it is a circle that winds $n$ times around the torous), and the map $(x,y)\mapsto yx^{-1}$ is a continous map on the torous, so it should still be continous in the fibered product.

But as noted in the discussion we had in the comments, the problem for these examples is in finding a consistent group structure on each fibre. If we had such a group structure it would yield a global zero section, but this would mean that we have an injective continous mapping from $\mathbb{S}^1\to \mathbb{R}$, that is not possible or an injective continous mapping $\mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^1$, the only one beeing the identity which is clearly not a section of $z\mapsto z^n$.

At least we can say that these are sheafs of $\mathbb{Z}$-sets, where $\mathbb{Z}$ acts transitively on the fibers.

Another example is the mobius band : take $[0,1]\times \mathbb{R}$, with the product topology and $\mathbb{R}$ endowed with the trivial topology, and take the quotient by the relation $(x_1,y_1)\sim (x_2,y_2)$ if and only if $x_1 = 0, x_2 = 1$ and $y_1 = -y_2$. Another one over $\mathbb{S}^1$ is the cylinder $\mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{R}$ with the product topology where once again $\mathbb{R}$ is given the discrete topology.

To produce more examples, take any abelian group $A$, and any isomorphism of abelian groups $f : A\to A$, then take $[0,1]\times A$ and quotient it by $(0,x)\sim (1,f(x))$, this will give an example of abelian sheaf in the sense of your definition.

Hope problems are solved now.

Comment: The map $TM\rightarrow M$ is not a sheaf by this definition since it is not a local homomorphism (the dimension of $TM$ is twice that of $M$). Same goes for the line bundles. I doubt that the $n$-fold covering $\mathbb{S}^1\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^1$ has a continuous operation $(s,t)\rightarrow s-t$... but it's quite tiresome to verify with the calculations... so I'll wait for a more satisfactory answer. Thanks!

Comment: Of course unless you locally trivialize the topology of $TM$ by making it into a direct product $\mathbb{R}^n_{\text{discrete}}\times U$.

Comment: Ah for the "known-elsewhere" I mean it is not a typical sheaf example like that of $\mathcal{C}^k$ functions, and I hope the example would be intuitive (drawable).

Comment: Thanks for your interest in my question. I gave you the correct-answer-check. Can you please verify that in your examples, the topology on $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{S}^1$ and $[0,1]$ is either discret or Zariski?

Comment: Ok, yes there is quite a problem, sorry ! We need to put the trivial topology on the group otherwise we do not have a local homeomorphism.

Comment: For the $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1$, can you describe the group structure on each fiber? (Let $\phi\in [0,2\pi)$, what is $f^{-1}(\phi)$, its $0$, its $+$?

Comment: I will write it in the answer but do we agree now that the map $(x,y)\mapsto y- x$ is continous on the subspace $\mathbb{R}\circ \mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: Ok I understand the problem now, it is not the fact that this map is not continous that causes it to fail, but the fact that there is no global section which is related to the problem of finding an abelian group strucutre on each fibre,  if we have one abelian group strucutre on each fiber it will give a global 0 section, (an abealian sheaf has always at least a global zero section) ! Sorry !